# Apache Spark 1.5 with Cassandra : Class cast exception

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

I use the following softwares:

> 1. Cassandra 2.1.9
> 2. Spark 1.5
> 3. Java using the Cassandra driver provided by Datastax.
> 4. Ubuntu 12.0.4

When I run spark locally using `local[8]`, the program runs fine and data is saved into Cassandra. However, when I submit the job to spark cluster, the following exception is thrown:

```
16 Sep 2015 03:08:58,808  WARN [task-result-getter-0] (Logging.scala:71) TaskSetManager - Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3,
192.168.50.131): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy to field scala.collection.Map$WithDefault.underlying of type scala.collection.Map in instance of scala.collection.immutable.Map$WithDefault
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2083)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1996)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am clueless how to fix this error. I use only the following 2 dependencies:

> 1. **spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar** --> Comes with Spark download
> 2. **spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.5.0-M1-SNAPSHOT.jar** --> Build from Git using sbt.

I have exported my bundled application jar into the spark classpath also.
Kindly help as I am not sure if this is an application specific error or a problem with Spark distribution itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issue finally.

The problem was that I was only adding my bundled Application jar (fat jar) into the spark context and excluded the following two jars:

> **1. spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar**
>
> **2. spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.5.0-M1-SNAPSHOT.jar**.

It turns out that I should also add **spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.5.0-M1-SNAPSHOT.jar** to the spark context and only exclude the **spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar**.

Comment: I'm having the same issue you had but I'm not able to understand your solution. I define the sparkconf as follows:

    
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(new String("New app"));
    sparkConf.setMaster("spark://xxx:7077");
    sparkConf.setAppName("Streambase Backend API");
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

Should I add something like this?

    String[] jars = {"/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar"};
    sparkConf.setJars(jars);