# Apache Spark: Uncaught exception in thread driver-heartbeater

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I wrote below simple spark program, using spark's StreamingContext and SQLContext.

**Note: The issue is reproducible, even without the streamingContext. Updated the program to reflect the same.**

**Note: Downgrading the spark version to 1.4.1 (I was using 1.5.2) seems to have fixed the issue for me. With spark also 1.5.1 the issue us reproducible.**

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "test")
    val sqc = new SQLContext(sc)

    val dataFrame = sqc.read.json(sc.textFile("<dir>"))
    println(dataFrame.groupBy("Product.SerialNumber").count().count())
    sc.stop()
}
```

This is giving below exception at the beginning but execution is proceeding and printing result.

```
15/11/25 15:48:55 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread driver-heartbeater
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics._accumulatorUpdates of type scala.collection.immutable.Map in instance of org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1163)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics.readObject(TaskMetrics.scala:219)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deserialize(Utils.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Executor.scala:440)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Executor.scala:430)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1.apply(Executor.scala:430)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1.apply(Executor.scala:428)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:428)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:472)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:472)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:472)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:472)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics._accumulatorUpdates of type scala.collection.immutable.Map in instance of org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskMetrics.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1160)
        ... 33 more
```

After 2 minutes, below exception happens and the execution is terminated. Till two minute the execution happens flawlessly and no issue/exception is reported.

```
15/11/25 15:51:44 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor driver with no recent heartbeats: 179219 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms^M
15/11/25 15:51:44 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor driver on localhost: Executor heartbeat timed out after 179219 ms^M
15/11/25 15:51:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 193.0 (TID 7688, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)^M
15/11/25 15:51:44 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 4 in stage 193.0 failed 1 times; aborting job^M
15/11/25 15:51:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 193.0 (TID 7691, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)^M
15/11/25 15:51:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 193.0 (TID 7690, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)^M
15/11/25 15:51:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 193.0 (TID 7689, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)^M
15/11/25 15:51:44 WARN SparkContext: Killing executors is only supported in coarse-grained mode^M
15/11/25 15:51:45 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1448446890000 ms.0^M
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 193.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.0 in stage 193.0 (TID 7688, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)^M
Driver stacktrace:^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)^M
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)^M
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)^M
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)^M
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)^M
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)^M
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)^M
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)^M
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1850)^M
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1921)^M
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:909)^M
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)^M
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)^M
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:310)^M
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:908)^M
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:177)^M
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1385)^M
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1385)^M
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)^M
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:1903)^M
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1384)^M
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.count(DataFrame.scala:1402)^M
        at main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:72)^M
        at main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:68)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:631)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:631)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:40)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)^M
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:34)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:218)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:218)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:218)^M
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)^M
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:217)^M
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)^M
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)^M
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)^M
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 193.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.0 in stage 193.0 (TID 7688, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)^M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may forget adding some dependency jars when you submit the spark job.
Try to assemble your project (so that all dependencies are included) before you submit it to spark:

```
sbt assembly
```

BTW, when I run

```
sbt console
```

and run commands inside scala interpreter, I will have the same problem as yours. But if I assemble it firstly and run the job by

```
spark submit --class className target/scala-2.10/xxx-assembly-0.1.0.jar someArgs
```

It works:)

ref: [Apache Spark 1.5 with Cassandra : Class cast exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606639/apache-spark-1-5-with-cassandra-class-cast-exception)

Comment: previously i was running using "sbt run". When i run with spark-submit there are other problems as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038913/spark-streaming-throwing-java-net-connectexception

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
val dataFrame = sqc.read.json(sc.textFile("<dir>")).cache()
```

I was having this same exact problem; running a `.count()` operation on the same dataframe too many times resulted in this error.

If that doesn't help, try this:

```
val dataFrame = sqc.read.json(sc.textFile("<dir>"))
val serialNumberDF = dataFrame.groupBy("Product.SerialNumber").cache()
println(serialNumberDF.count().count())
```

My guess is that having to re-evaluate the dataframe over and over (since dataframes are lazily evaluated) caused an error somewhere. And plus, with large amounts of data, using a dataframe in multiple places can be pretty costly on performance without caching.

Answer (score 0):

In our case (Spark 1.6.1), these same errors were showing up somewhat randomly while running tests via sbt. And the issue actually seems to be an [sbt issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/89). The work-around (mentioned in the link above) is to run the tests in a forked jvm:

`fork in test := true`