# Spark Streaming throwing java.net.ConnectException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Below simple spark program runs absolutely fine, if I run as "sbt run". But if i run,

1) As "`spark-submit.cmd eventfilter-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`". where the jar is created using "sbt assembly" with "streaming and sql"'s sbt rule with "% provided".

2) As "`spark-submit.cmd --jar play-json_2.10-2.3.10.jar seventfilter_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`".

Both cases, it is starting and waiting for new files to come. No problem till now.

But as soon as I start putting the files, so that it can be streamed, below exception comes.

Note: I am using spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6,

Note: If I run through "sbt run", it runs smooth for hours.

Note: I tried with 1.5.2 also, by changing sbt file accordingly. The behavior is same.

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:639)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:398)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:390)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
```

sbt file

---

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.10"
```

scala file

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf
      .setMaster("local[*]")    //Comment if executing through spark-submit
      .setAppName("test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(3))

    val dStream = ssc.textFileStream("dir")
    val  expandedEventStream = dStream.count().print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have virtuaBox setup and by default spark used that IP to find the application jar. After disabling the virtualBox IPs spark started working fine.